# VBA Excel combobox not displaying the value after selecting option

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, populate

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

    If ComboBox1.ListCount > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Clear
    End If

    For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
    ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name
    Next N

End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA so please bear with me.  I may not be doing this the best way to begin with.

The code is taking the names of each sheet in my workbook (with the exception of the last sheet) and adding them to a combobox list.  At first, each time I clicked the drop down, all sheet names were being added again making the list continue to grow with every click.  My remedy was to clear the combobox first on each click and repopulate.

However, with the clear option being used, the value is not being displayed when making my selection.  It displays fine when not using the clear option.  Everything else still works, but I need it to show the selected value so users aren't confused.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I need?

EDIT: If it matters, this is not in a user form, it's just a active x combobox located directly on a worksheet.

Comment: `Is there a better way to accomplish what I need?` - Exactly what is it that you want the combobox to do? You mention what doesn't work, but not what you want to happen.

Comment: All I need is for it to show in the box the selection that was made.  Instead it just remains empty after choosing one.  This doesn't happen when I'm not using the clear option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a very strange behavior - but the DopButtonClick event is triggered again when you select the item in the list. Therefore, the value that was just assigned get cleared upon the `.Clear` in the second run.

This code fixes it:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim strValue As String
    Dim n As Integer
    strValue = ComboBox1.Value

    If ComboBox1.ListCount > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Clear
    End If

    For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
        ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name
    Next n
    ComboBox1.Value = strValue

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm new so I guess I can't vote you up, but this fixed the problem.  thanks so much.  also thanks for saying it was strange behavior.  I thought i was just crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below would work.  However, I'd question why you'd want to repopulate the combobox everytime someone clicks on it.  Why not do it when the workbook opens or the worksheet is activated?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick(ComboBox1 As ComboBox)
    Dim strSelected As String
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then
      strSelected = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.ListCount > 0 Then
      ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Clear
    End If

    For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
      ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name
      If strSelected = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name Then
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = N - 1
      End If
    Next N
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 - 1 min faster - and also taking care of the case that nothing is selected! :-)

Comment: @Peter Albert, your solution is better.  Just check for a zero length string.  Mine does the logical test on every loop cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice solution Peter. 
In my case I have a list of items that can change between two combobox runs. If the selected combobox item is not anymore in the combo list, at the next run, the line:

```
ComboBox1.Value = strValue
```

throws an error .

I've found that declaring a public index:

```
Public nr As Integer
```

and making a count inside the combobox code in order to run .clear only once per button action makes this working independently of the list update:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
Dim n As Integer

If nr = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.Clear
    nr = 1
Else
    nr = 0
End If

For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 1
    ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name
Next n
End Sub
```